# How to set BIOS file in go PSX emulator free?

Tags: technical-issues, android, emulation, ps1

How to set BIOS file in Go PSX Emulator Free? I have the BIOS file but I cannot set it for some reason.

I select with Gran Turismo 2 Simulation mode game (file .bin) and have

> **Warning BIOS file**
>
> No setting of a valid BIOS file. Are you sure you want to migrate to the setting screen? If you want to continue in this state to work with HLE (BIOS simulation) the operation becomes unstable

I press **Setting Bios File** and get

> BIOS file is not set
>
> ...Copy the BIOS files obtained from your PS1 to your device press the automatic search button. If you can not find in the auto search select the desired BIOS file manually setting button

I cannot find either of these buttons, where are they? How do I set the BIOS file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Own answer**

Use **FPse** instead of go PSX and bios will be working (if you point bios location)

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a BIOS file you still need to put it in the correct location.

From PSX tutorial regarding [BIOS setup](http://fantasyanime.com/emuhelp/psx#bios-setup):

> Extract the BIOS from its zip file. Drag "Scph1001.bin" to pSX's BIOS folder, as shown below:
>
> [image: Placing BIOS file in 'bios' folder]
>
> Open pSX. Go to File > Configuration, as shown below:
>
> [image: Context Menu]
>
> Click on the BIOS tab. Then click the <kbd>...</kbd> button (shown below). Select the “Scph1001.bin” BIOS file, then click Open.
>
> [image: Configuration, BIOS Tab]
>
> Click OK. Then close pSX. The next time you open pSX, it will be ready for you load a game.

Comment: I want to play on mobile on Android not PC (I mean not now on PC but PC's hints are helpful too)